# Cannot connect to the wireless internet on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, internet

Following [this](https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_linux.html#setting-up-the-real-time-kernel) , I installed the real-time kernel 5.9.1 for Ubuntu 20.04.5.
After enter Ubuntu system with this kernel, Ubuntu cannot connect to  wireless internet.
Wireless internet icon does not appear on the top right.

```
d@xdpx:~/Desktop$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net 
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f0] (rev 01) 
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (16) I219-V [8086:1a1f] (rev 01)  
  Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (16) I219-V [17aa:50a0]
```

According to some answer, I downloaded iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0.tgz from  [intel @ Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz](https://www.intel.cn/content/www/cn/zh/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html),

```
tar  -zxvf  iwlwifi-Qu-48.13675109.0.tgz
cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

However, it does not work.

```
ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 
       ether 9c:2d:cd:12:47:a2 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) 
       RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) 
       RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 
       TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) 
       TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0 
       device interrupt 16 memory 0xae300000-ae320000 

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host> 
        loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback) 
        RX packets 4951 bytes 355561 (355.5 KB) 
        RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 
        TX packets 4951 bytes 355561 (355.5 KB) 
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

with the origin kernel that can connect to  wireless internet

```
ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:2d:cd:12:47:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xae300000-ae320000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 541  bytes 46708 (46.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 541  bytes 46708 (46.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.144  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::ae63:6e56:d6e9:66af  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:7a:0e:bd:fd:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10077  bytes 6533823 (6.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4882  bytes 1700025 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Where did you get this kernel and why do you think you need it? Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is based on the long-term supported Linux release series 5.4. HWE stack updated to Linux release series 5.8.

Comment: Accoding to this [Setting up the real-time kernel](https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/installation_linux.html#setting-up-the-real-time-kernel)

Comment: Ubuntu is only tested to use some real time kernels. I suggest you do some research and make sure the one you are trying to use is one that is know to work.